# May Corda oracles propose transactions?

Tags: corda

From a Corda business network design perspective, may Corda oracles propose transactions? Reading the Corda Docs about oracles, my impression is "no", but maybe I'm misreading, or reading too much into the docs, e.g.,

> "Oracles are network services that, upon request, provide commands that encapsulate a specific fact (e.g. the exchange rate at time x) and list the oracle as a required signer."

ref: https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V2.0/key-concepts-oracles.html?highlight=oracle

Answer (score 0):

Oracles are just regular Corda nodes, and any Corda node can serve as an oracle, provided it is trusted to provide a certain set of facts. Although oracles may differ from other nodes from a *business* perspective in that they are recognised providers of trusted facts, they are identical from a *technical* perspective.